# Why is a function returned as null when being appended, or set as textContent?

Tags: javascript, function

Just something I haven't quite figured out and wanted to get an answer on why it works this way.

```
const print_html = (param) => {
  let container = document.querySelector('Container');
  console.log(test_function(param)); // Why does this log the string?
  container.textConent = test_function(param) // ... But the function is null here?
}

const test_function = (name) => {
  return `My name is ${name}`;
};

print_html('Jermaine')
```

The line with console log will print the correct string to the console as expected, but how come the line below won't set the textContent of the container to the the string?

Comment: I think you want to query for `'#Container'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have type in your `textContent` also your query selector is wrong, it should be `.container`

```js
const print_html = (param) => {
  let container = document.querySelector('.container');
  console.log(test_function(param)); // Why does this log the string?
  container.textContent = test_function(param) // ... But the function is null here?
}

const test_function = (name) => {
  return `My name is ${name}`;
};

print_html('Jermaine')
```

```html
<div class="container"></div>
```

**Edit**

As pointed by [Icepickle](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3231537/icepickle) the query selector `Container` can be correct provided HTML markup used is `<Container></Container>`

Comment: Just as a short note, `Container` might be correct if he is referring to a self created element tag ;) As an example, you can see it [here](https://jsfiddle.net/kaqp3m7u/)

Comment: @Icepickle yes correct,  that did not cross my mind, I will update the answer.